# Alpine Expression Error: show is not defined

Tags: npm, module, alpine.js

alpinejs not working when following installation instructions.
I am following the instructions from [Codechef](https://www.codecheef.org/article/how-to-install-and-use-alpine-js-in-laravel-8) to install alpine.

I use it in my blade.php like this:

```
 <script src="{{ asset('js/alpine.js') }}"></script>
 <!-- other elements ommitted for brevity -->
 <div x-data=""{ show: false}>
     <button @click="show = ! show">{{ __("Position")  }}</button>
     <div x-show="show">
         <a href="#">One</a>
         <a href="#">Two</a>
         <a href="#">Three</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

My layout.blade.php contains the line

```
   <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.10.5/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
```

When I open the page, I get the following error:

> Alpine Expression Error: show is not defined
>
> Expression: "show"

What could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<div x-data="{show: false}">
```

(you wrote instead:

```
<div x-data=""{show: false}>
```

that is not correct)